# gcc error: expected expression before 'else'

Tags: c, gcc

I'm wondering why such code generates following error while compiling:

1.c:11: error: expected expression before 'else'

code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define xprintk(...)    while(0); 


int main (void)
{
 if (1)
    xprintk("aaa\n");
 else
    xprintk("bbb\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 #define xprintk(...)    while(0)
                                ^^ Remove semi-colon
```

See what happens after pre-processing

`gcc -E test.c`

```
int main (void)
{
 if (1)
    while(0);; //<- Two semi-colon (i.e. Two statements)
 else
    while(0);; //<- Two semi-colon

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the entirety of your code? Regardless of that, it's because after macro expansion, your code follows the form of:

```
if (1) 
    stmt1; 
    stmt2; 
    stmt ... // Possibly more statements than this depending on the macro
else 
    stmt3;
```

This is not a valid form for the `if-else` construct, hence an error.

Comment: Adding to what you have mentioned above, having braces around the if condition block would solve the problem too. But thats like a workaround to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to remove the semicolon in the macro definition (as in previous answer) so it doesn't lead to duplicate semicolons, and replace while(0) with do{}while(0), this way the compiler will report an error if you miss the semicolon when you're using xprintk(), rather than confusing the next statement for the body of the while loop.